# Getting image from google api

Tags: ios, json

```
{
geometry: 
{
   location: 
   {
      lat: 20.012256,
      lng: 73.761541
   }
},
icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/fitness-71.png",
id: "3e59d6a764e44c969e632c659e0d4284e7bd2561",
name: "AYURVEDIC PANCHKARMA & GARBHASANSKAR",
photos: [
{
height: 1024,
html_attributions: ["From a Google User"],
photo_reference: "CpQBjQAAAIn74syEAB4wtDfRxQqHrEuETcQYYJ2PgAy-uCtQ5UjSsfmWhGLvij6zL4rdHCEUSHOvKOyyhcOO7N-i-mcYpAjZKMNgbfNEaBNWPPRl6MTRf3BHb8DZ8i8bO-F3-IVF5kEvo4-8GQwDGsvNiIXdmkyTi0ugzo0Tj3K9Zicy-cakr25sgy8Mp-UeBqyPABv_AhIQIJzI11nBcIQWVHPBnSVMihoU69ou9PsrnIrvldruNVJma9EGnRU",
width: 768
}
],
place_id: "ChIJmx2FRZDr3TsRgNITjVbXAyU",
reference: "CpQBhQAAAH6wIR1m39e0NaDGqSvFAb6LHjcY3YzZbHJV33RRScqspe4s6NPNpMQZbufkMHhDv7-zhbYriOct-s1jX1Uy_tP4a6cgPboaBITMpgLR_uQO7j-k8ngDgvYuIeU70So0m-RygRMwK5Wsxj-j-dW6UswEIGiyctBvWD_eIW7j1dHh9GfS1YhBGAjDcEZuAOjNARIQOgtBWeqaHi6rPsZgc7g9TBoUBuz5fgZnaIwkGgZP8MiZG97fRl0",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"gym",
"health",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "'Anand -Leela', 37, Kamal Society, Near Kusumagraj Pratishtan, Gangapur Road, Na, Nashik"
}
```

I am using following web service through which i want to access the photo_reference to get the image, API is in JSON format.How can i retrieve the image from photo_reference

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am accessing it via this link but it is not showing the image.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photo_reference=CpQBjQAAAIn74syEAB4wtDfRxQqHrEuETcQYYJ2PgAy-uCtQ5UjSsfmWhGLvij6zL4rdHCEUSHOvKOyyhcOO7N-i-mcYpAjZKMNgbfNEaBNWPPRl6MTRf3BHb8DZ8i8bO-F3-IVF5kEvo4-8GQwDGsvNiIXdmkyTi0ugzo0Tj3K9Zicy-cakr25sgy8Mp-UeBqyPABv_AhIQIJzI11nBcIQWVHPBnSVMihoU69ou9PsrnIrvldruNVJma9EGnRU&key=AIzaSyCk0pxYnuXC_AOi6OKqADQZK449u0V_gpk

Comment: can u give ur google api url ., i give the answer for u

Comment: also how to see that image on browser.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=20.0126177,73.7542103&radius=1000&types=gym&key=key